# Webpack for completely static project (no JS / TS at all)

Tags: webpack, webpack-config, copy-webpack-plugin

My project is a JSON schema consisting of multiple JSON files:

```
src
├── a.json
├── b.json
└── c.json
```

All I want to do is to replace a `version` placeholder in this files with a version from `package.json`. I.e. `a.json` contains a `${version}` (actual syntax is arbitrary, I don't have any preferences) placeholder in it's `$id`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "$id": "https://foo.bar/${version}/a.json",
  "type": "object",
  …
}
```

And, assuming the `version` in `package.json` is `1.0.0` I want to process this JSON and get:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "$id": "https://foo.bar/1.0.0/a.json",
  "type": "object",
  …
}
```

And that's it. It can be achieved by a script like this (in `package.json`):

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist && cp src/*.json dist/ && sed -i'' -e \"s/\\${version}/$npm_package_version/\" dist/*.json",
}
```

But how do I do it with Webpack?

I know about copy and define plugins, but it seems that I need actual source in my project to be an entry point for Webpack. A config like this:

```json
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: 'none',
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: "src/*.json",
                },
            ],
        }),
    ],
};
```

Copies files to `dist` (or wherever I want), but gives an error:

```
ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/home/madhead/Projects/schema'
```

Another question here is how to copy and process those files (replace placeholders).

How do I only copy and process those JSONs with Webpack?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {from: 'src/*.json',
        to: '[name].[ext]',
        transform(content) {
            return content.toString().replace(/\${version}/g, '1.0.12');
        }
    }
])
```

And btw have no idea why you want to do this with webpack if you already know how to do it with basic script so you can just do it before or after webpack build.

Comment: Well, because shell script is not portable, and Webpack is.